# Exception handling with sql.rows from a Quartz job

Tags: groovy, quartz-scheduler

I am using a groovy.sql.Sql.rows(sql, parameters) inside a quartz job to call a stored procedure. At times the stored proc times out but it doesn't propagate the exception to the calling code. For ex in the following code the exception never makes it to the try/catch block-

```
            try{
                    res = db.rows(sql, parameter) //db is of type groovy.sql.Sql
                } 
                catch(Exception e) {
                    log.error("error in calling the proc", e)
                }
```

The only thing I see in the logs is a warning from sql.SQL which looks like this -

```
[quartzScheduler_Worker-1] WARN  sql.Sql  - Failed to execute: { call stored_prod_name(?, ?, ?, ?) } because: JZ006: Caught IOException: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
```

After this my entire JVM hangs! I would like to recover from a timeout but I can't seem to catch the exception. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: And the question is?

Comment: Updated with the question